# How can I get the monthly sales with change in prices?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Please help out a newbie if you can.

I have two tables, one contains individual sales:

| item id | transaction date | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2023.01.20 | A |
| 102 | 2023.02.12 | A |
| 103 | 2023.05.25 | B |
| 102 | 2023.06.04 | C |
| 101 | 2023.11.24 | B |

and the other contains the prices of the items during certain periods.

| item ID | price | valid from | valid to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 2023.01.01 | 2023.05.31 |
| 101 | 3 | 2023.06.01 | 2023.12.31 |
| 102 | 5 | 2023.01.01 | 2023.12.31 |
| 103 | 4 | 2023.01.01 | 2023.12.31 |

How would you make a report which shows what was the total sales value in certain months/quarters?

Connecting many to many certainly did not work, I also tried to put a middle table between them with only item IDs

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add a Calculated Column to your first table that gets the Price from the second table.

```
Price = 
  var thisId = [item id]
  var thisDate = [transaction date]
  var result =
    CALCULATE(
      MIN(Table2[Price]),
      Table2[item ID] = thisId &&
      Table2[valid from] <= thisDate && thisDate <= Table2[valid to]
    )

  return result
```